# How can I write a gem in Ruby on Rails to check md5 checksum for a file which is stored on Amazon S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rubygems, md5

I want to write a gem in RoR to check md5 checksum, the file is stored on Amazon S3. When the user download that file, the gem should check md5 checksum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be obtainable via an HTTP GET request to the S3 URL and getting the `If-None-Match` header, which is represented as the MD5 hash of a file.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html